# how to make an image responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I need your help in order to make this logo responsive. Thank you !
Here's a link to a visual representation of the issue : https://gyazo.com/7f4b031ab954b4231b079fdbca292628 gyazo is gif capture program.

```
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-color:#d495a8;
}
.showcasemedia{
    width:60px;
    transition:0.25s all ease;
}
.showcasemedia:hover{
       -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
        cursor:pointer;
}
#header li{
    float:left;
    margin-top:4.5px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
.logoheader{
    transition: 0.5s all;
    margin-left: 38%;
}
.logoheader:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.95);
    cursor:pointer;
}
#header p{
    float:right;
    font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
    color:white;
    font-size:37px;
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:15px;
    transition:0.5s all;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#navbar{
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#ae657b;
}
#navbar li{
    float:left;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-top:5px;
    color:white;
}

#navbar ul{
    margin-left:39.75%;
}



  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tajawal" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
        <title>Petnation index</title>
    <body>

    <div id="header"><!--Deschid div principal-->
            <ul><!--Deschid ul social media-->
                <li><img src="poze/facebook.png" class="showcasemedia"></li>
                <li><img src="poze/instagram.png" class="showcasemedia"></li>
            </ul><!--Inchis ul social media-->
            <img src="poze/logoscris.png" class="logoheader">
            <p>Paws make the laws!</p>
    </div><!--Inchis div principal-->

    <div id="navbar"><!--Deschid div principal-->
        <ul><!--Deschid ul navbar-->
            <li>Download</li>
            <li>Features</li>
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul><!--Inchis ul navbar-->
    </div><!--Inchis div principal-->

    </body>
    </html>
```

ps : I've edited this post in order to get some upvotes (I have been throttled for not reason and im trying to get rid of the "ban") Thank you and hope you understand. The issue remains.

Comment: You need to share sample code in order to get help and please be more clear in what you ask for. Do you want help with CSS?

Comment: Yes I need the logo to go as close as it can get to the social media buttons before i make another design for the smaller devices.

Comment: here's the code : https://pastebin.com/iPf4j9dE AND https://pastebin.com/LFGGnyeL

Comment: Can I have a working demo where I can make edits to CSS code.

Comment: @EnderAdy Please include the relevant code in the post itself. I'm not going to download an unknown file to answer your question.

Comment: No, I do have to download something. Even if I didn't, I shouldn't have to leave this site.

Comment: how would you like me to send you the source ?

Comment: I've already said — include it in the question.

Comment: its too long, just check the pastebin, if we presume you're a webdev you should know pastebin is legit

Comment: @EnderAdy I will not restate this. You should have a [mcve]. If that's too long, then it's not minimal. I know pastebin is real, that's not the point. This isn't even to mention the fact that this question is too broad.

Comment: @EnderAdy You do not need to paste all the code in question, just the relevant snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update following code:

```
<div id="header"><!--Deschid div principal-->
    <ul style="float:left"><!--Deschid ul social media-->
        <li><img src="poze/facebook.png" class="showcasemedia"></li>
        <li><img src="poze/instagram.png" class="showcasemedia"></li>
    </ul><!--Inchis ul social media-->
    <img src="poze/logoscris.png" class="logoheader">
    <div style="float:right;">
        <p>Paws make the laws!</p>
    </div>
```

Also update following in CSS:

```
    #header{
        width:100%;
        height:70px;
        text-align:center; //added this line
        background-color:#d495a8;
    }
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: Thank you but what i need is 3 elements, the social media icons, the logo and the text, i want the left one to float left the right one to float right and the center one to stay in the middle. Once i start resizing the whole webpage i want the center image to gradually go towards the left as the text does untill it cant get any closer and then i use the meta tags to design it for smaller screens